# Phonegap Build app can't find Javascript file

Tags: javascript, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

My experience with Phonegap Build has got a little rusty in the last year and I'm having an issue with it.

Here's the `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="uk.co.example.app" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>Example App</name>
    <description>
        The Example app
    </description>
    <author href="http://www.example.co.uk/" email="user@example.co.uk">
        Example User 
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="~1.5.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="file://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

And the `www/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
        <title>Example App</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <base href="/">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div ng-app="app" ng-csp ng-cloak ng-class="{'reverse':reverse}">
                <div loadingspinner id="loadingspinner"></div>
                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
</html>
```

The file structure looks like this:

```
config.xml
www/
   index.html
   css/
       style.css
   js/
       bundle.js
```

Now, the CSS file loads and works fine, but the Javascript file doesn't. If I set up some JS inline, that works, but any external Javascript I try to use, no matter how small or simple, doesn't work, even if it's just triggering an alert. It works fine in a web browser, however, and I believe the path is correct - the file resides in at `www/js/bundle.js`.

I think it's something to do with the content security policy and the whitelist plugin as that's been introduced since I last worked on an app with Phonegap Build, and it seems fairly logical, but I can't see what the issue is. The remote debugger doesn't display any error, so I'm at a loss as to what's going on. Can anyone see where I've gone awry?

If it helps, this is on Android. I haven't tried it on iOS as I don't have an iOS device, so it could be platform specific.

Comment: Here's what I use : <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' gap://ready file://* 'unsafe-inline' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; img-src *">

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. Also, now I think about it I think it should raise an error in the Phonegap Build debugger if that's the problem.

Comment: have you tried to remove <base href="/">

Comment: @Eric I shall give that a go

Comment: @Eric No, doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: You say your JS doesnt load? You should get an error in the console though.. Can you try another file, like a js file with alert('test') in it so we're sure it's not loading..

Comment: @Eric Just tried that and it's not firing. The demo app created by the Phonegap CLI works OK, so I'm going to start copying over files from that and see when it starts working. That might at least give a clue where the issue lies

Comment: I haven't figured out exactly what the problem is, but I have been able to prevent it from occurring.by copying over the `index.html` from the boilerplate Phonegap app generated by the CLI and amending that.

Comment: I can't spare time to resolve it now for this app as it's a work thing, but I've been experiencing the same issue for a personal app so I'll figure out what the problem actually is on that and post an answer in case anyone else has the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Remove the next meta tag from your code and all should work:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
```

Comment: Nope, still happening

Comment: And you don't have any errors or warnings in the console?

Comment: Nope, nothing at all

Answer (score 0):

move the scripts inside the body tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    </body>
```